# File Download Java without Temporary file

Tags: java, rest, file, download

I am trying to create a file and send as a response so that file can be downloaded. I am not sure how to do it. My current code

```
  String fileName = "fileToBeSaved.csv";
  File file = new File(fileName);
  FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
  writer.append(data);
  writer.flush();
  writer.close();

  Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
  response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"fileName.csv\"");

  return response.build();
```

This code creates a temporary file on my system. And when the browser receives the response it gets the path to file, like "C:/folderName/FileName"...Upon mentioning this path on the browser, I get the option to download the file.

What I want to achieve is:
I want to create a file (But don't want any temporary file to be created on my system) and send as a response. The browser should receive a prompt asking whether to download the file or not as a response.
Can some one guide me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want to create a file but you don't want to create a file? NB The cast to `(Object)` isn't necessary.

Comment: I don't want temporary file to be created on my system. Isn't there any way to say when asked for download, create a file with these contents?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the way.

```
Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok();
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename.csv\"");
response.entity(contentAsString);
return response.build();
```

If you cannot build a string out of the contents of the file, then a work-around is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bo));
//for loop can be any content.. I am just showing a represenatation.
for (int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++) {
    writer.write(content.get(i));
}
writer.flush();
Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok();
response.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment");
response.entity(bo.toByteArray());
return response.build();
```

In the above code, I am building a file and sending to GUI. No temporary file was created.

Hope it helps.

Thanks!